# How to change environment variables for VLC on macOS?

Tags: macos

Recently, I was working on a project when I cam upon the following instruction (one of the many here: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Mac#3---install-dependencies) :

After you've installed VLC, set the following environment variables:

VLC_PATH: point this to the VLC libs folder. Sample Mac OS X location: /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib

VLC_PLUGIN_PATH: point this to the VLC plugins folder. Sample Mac OS X location: /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins

How does one do the following? I am using High Sierra, macOS. My Shell is ZSH.

---

I moved this question from the apple Stackexchange as this is more related to a developer issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily, I would take that to mean you need to edit your login script, e.g. `$HOME/.profile` and add the following near the bottom:

```
export VLC_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib
export VLC_PLUGIN_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins
```

Once you have changed it, either log out and log in again, or start a new Terminal (closing all existing open Terminals) for it to take effect.